# I'm having problems with the .split() method using "," as the delimeter. Java

Tags: java

So for my current school project we have to read input from a file containing info on the periodic table of elements. Essentially I have to seperate bits of each line which has info on an element and put them into seperate string values.

Here the bit of code I'm having problems with.

```
for(int i=0;inputStream.hasNextLine();i++)
    {
        String line = inputStream.nextLine();
        String[] info = line.split(",");

        name=info[0];
        atomicNumber=info[1];
        symbol=info[2];
        boilingPoint=info[3];
        meltingPoint=info[4];
        density=info[5];
        molecularWeight=info[6];


        elementInfo[i]= new Element(name,atomicNumber,symbol,boilingPoint,meltingPoint,density,molecularWeight);
```

It stores everything in the proper place except for the information for the density and the molecular Weight which i get null values for. I couldn't find any info why it isn't working for those last two Strings.

Example output:

Element Name: actinium

Atomic Number: 89

Symbol: Ac

Boiling Point: 3470

Melting Point: 1324

Density: null

Molecular Weight: null

Here's the constructor for the element object:

```
public Element(String name,String atomicNumber,String symbol, String boilingPoint, String meltingPoint, String density, String molecularWeight)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.atomicNumber=atomicNumber;
    this.symbol=symbol;
    this.boilingPoint=boilingPoint;
    this.meltingPoint=meltingPoint;
    this.density=density;
    this.molecularWeight=molecularWeight;
}
```

Comment: What does the actinium line look like in the file?

Comment: Can you show the input data (specifically the line for the example you provided)?

Comment: most probably you have empty lines as last 2 string

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the input file that you are reading from?

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this,**

> // mean into file that info not exist, in that case take its default i.e. empty

```
info[5] == null ? "empty" : info[5]; 
info[6] == null ? "empty" : info[6];
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the file you are reading contains 7 elements, else the following code will result in an error

density=info[5];     molecularWeight=info[6];

Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String line = "1,2,3,4,5,,";
    String[] info = line.split(",");
    System.out.println(info.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(info));
}
```

The Output of the above snippet is 5 and [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Here we cannot use info[5] or info[6] as it will result in an error.

So your data is correct and you are capturing all the values.
I believe the problem is in printing the output, but you have not mentioned that code in your query to investigate deep.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

`String.split()` never ever returns null (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))), which means the problem is not with split() method but, elsewhere. The split() method seem to return at least 7 chunks of data and this is because you are not getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` when you do this `molecularWeight=info[6]`.

Then the problem is elsewhere and you can find out by reviewing your code and there must be something you are missing, something really really simple.

Let's assume you have the following input (2 elements):

```
actinium,89,Da,3470,1926,missing-x,missing-y
actinium,13,Gk,5480,1124,missing-z,missing-w
```

I used majority of your code, and developed a sample use cases to read the above two elements from file and store them in a list and print them back. I used `List<Element>` instead of your `Element[]` solution as well as overrided toString() in Element class to pretty-print the elements with Java 8's stream, see below and compare with your solution:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFromFileElements {
    public static void main(String... args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // You can use list instead of Element[] array
        List<Element> elementInfo = new ArrayList<Element>(); 

        //file containing the input
        File file = new File("C:\\test_java\\elements.txt"); 

        //open input stream to the file
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file); 

        //as long as there is nextLine() keep looping
        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] chunk = line.split(",");

            Element e = new Element(chunk[0], chunk[1], chunk[2], chunk[3], chunk[4], chunk[5],
                    chunk[6]);

            //add to the list of Element/s
            elementInfo.add(e); 
        }

        //close input stream
        input.close(); 

        //java 8 stream iterator through collection
        elementInfo.stream().forEach((temp) -> {
            //temp.toString() uses the overrided toString() of element class
            System.out.println(temp.toString()); 
        }); 
    }
}

class Element {
    String name;
    String atomicNumber;
    String symbol;
    String boilingPoint;
    String meltingPoint;
    String density;
    String molecularWeight;

    public Element(String name, String atomicNumber, String symbol, String boilingPoint, String meltingPoint,
            String density, String molecularWeight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.atomicNumber = atomicNumber;
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.boilingPoint = boilingPoint;
        this.meltingPoint = meltingPoint;
        this.density = density;
        this.molecularWeight = molecularWeight;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder  = new StringBuilder(); 
        builder.append("\n Element name: " + this.name); 
        builder.append("\n Atomic no: " + this.atomicNumber); 
        builder.append("\n Symobl : " + this.symbol); 
        builder.append("\n Boiling point : " + this.boilingPoint); 
        builder.append("\n Melting point : " + this.meltingPoint); 
        builder.append("\n Density : " + this.density); 
        builder.append("\n Molecular weight: " + this.molecularWeight); 

        return builder.toString();

    }
}
```

And running the above code against the above two lines in the file, I get the following input:

```
Element name: actinium
 Atomic no: 89
 Symobl : Da
 Boiling point : 3470
 Melting point : 1926
 Density : missing-x
 Molecular weight: missing-y

 Element name: actinium
 Atomic no: 13
 Symobl : Gk
 Boiling point : 5480
 Melting point : 1124
 Density : missing-z
 Molecular weight: missing-w
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
       public static void readFileData(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
        ArrayList<Element> list = new arrayList<>();
        String split = ","; //split with comma

                Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));

                String wordIn;
                Element elem = new Element();

                while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                    wordIn = in.nextLine();
                    String splitter[] = wordIn.split(split);

                    String name = splitter[0];
                    int atomicNumber = Integer.parseInt(splitter[1]);
                    String symbol = splitter[2];
                    String boilingPoint = splitter[3];
                    String meltingPoint = splitter[4];
                    String density = splitter[5];
                    String molecularWeight = splitter[6]

                    elem.setName(name);
                    elem.setAtomicNumber(atomicNumber);
                    elem.setSymbol(symbol);
                    elem.setBoilingPoint(boilingPoint);
                    elem.setMeltingPoint(meltingPoint);
                    elem.setDensity(density);
                    elem.setMolecularWeight(molecularWeight);
                    list.add(elem);
    }
                  for(Element el : list){
                     sout(el.toString()) // if you have a to string method
                  }
}

     public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String file = sc.next();
        readFileData(file);
     }
```

Make sure you have those setters in your `Element` class. And a too String method would be handy but not necessary. If the variable is type `int` in your `Element` class the you can do `Integer.parseInt()` or `Double.parseDouble` which converts string to integer or float etc. sout is short for `System.out.println();` type sout + tab and you get the full thing.